# How do I access Windows Azure account token using Python 3.3

Tags: python, http, azure, httpconnection

I am new to programming and I am looking to access Windows translate token using Python 3.3. MS have guidelines [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512433.aspx) for C# and PHP but I don't seem to be able to replicate their success in Python. 
The code is falling over at the HTTPConnection stage.

**Edit [14 May]:** I found some improvements that seem to be helping

My simple code to connect is:

```
from suds.client import Client
import http.client

# Initialize variables:
wsdlUrl = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Soap.svc"
clientID = "ID";
clientSecret = "SECRET"
authUrl = "https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13/"
scopeUrl = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com"
grantType = "client_credentials"

def getTokens(grantType, scopeUrl, clientID, clientSecret, authUrl):
    headers = {"grant_type": grantType, "client_id": clientID, "client_secret":         clientSecret, "scope": scopeUrl}
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net')
    conn.request("POST", "/v2/OAuth2-13", "", headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print(response.status, response.reason)


getTokens(grantType, scopeUrl, clientID, clientSecret, authUrl)
```

The error now receive is:
400 Bad Request

I have researched this error and where answers were provided it tended to be reasonably straightforward to fix. I have checked the code with these fixes but to no avail.

I guess this is a reasonably common problem for anyone wanting to work with Azure and needing to access the token?

If you have any suggestions on how to diagnose this error or better methods to get the access key, kindly share please.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. MS have a useful tool for debugging here: http://oauthdevconsole.cloudapp.net/PartialOAuth

In the end the solution was that the headers needed to be converted to a string and a workaround for an unusual character in the secret had to be modified using the tool above.

The final code is here:

```
def getTokens(grantType, scopeUrl, clientID, clientSecret, authUrl):
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net')
    conn.request("POST", "/v2/OAuth2-13/", "client_id="+clientID+"&client_secret="+clientSecret+"&grant_type=client_credentials&scope="+scopeUrl)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print(response.status, response.reason)
```

Best regards,

- Rob